# Add 'See on Map' Link in Fusion Tables Map List View

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am using the wonderful Fusion Tables Map Template by [Derek Eder](http://derekeder.com/searchable_map_template/). I have activated the results list as instructed by him [here](https://github.com/derekeder/FusionTable-Map-Template/wiki/List-search-results).

I would like to have a 'See on Map' link on each listing so that when i click on the link the page scrolls up to the map and opens an infowindow for that particular listing. You can see an example on the [geo places](http://templatic.com/demos/geoplaces/placecategory/famous-buildings/) theme.

Below is my code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.spacelab.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-responsive.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css"/>
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->


  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='navbar'>
      <div class='navbar-inner'>
        <div class='container'>
          <a class='brand' href='/'>Worldwide Stores</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div class='row-fluid'>
        <div class='span4'>


          <div class='well'>
            <h4>
              Address <small>(<a id='find_me' href='#'>find me</a>)</small>
            </h4>
            <input class='input-block-level' id='search_address' placeholder='Enter an address or an intersection' type='text' />
            <label>
              show companies within
              <select class='input-small' id='search_radius'>
                <option value='400'>2 blocks</option>
                <option value='805'>1/2 mile</option>
                <option value='1610'>1 mile</option>
                <option value='3220'>2 miles</option>
                <option value='8050'>5 miles</option>
                <option value='16100'>10 miles</option>
                <option value='40250'>25 miles</option>
                <option value='80500'>50 miles</option>
                <option value='161000'>100 miles</option>
                <option value='402500'>250 miles</option>
                <option value='805000'>500 miles</option>
                <option value='1610000'>1000 miles</option>
              </select>

            </label>


                    <h5> Refine Your Search By:</h5>
                        <label>
                            <select id='select_type'>
                             <option value=''>All Categories</option>
                             <option value='Hotels'>Hotels</option>
                             <option value='Restaurants'>Restaurants</option>
                             <option value='Shopping Malls'>Shopping Malls</option>
                             <option value='Travel Agents'>Travel Agents</option>
                            </select>
                            </label>

                            <label>
                            <select disabled id='select_type1'>
                            <option value=''>Select Two</option>
                            <option value='male'>Male</option>
                            <option value='female'>Female</option>
                            </select>
                            </label>

                            <label>
                            <select disabled id='select_type2'>
                            <option value=''>Select Three</option>
                            <option value='Advanced Materials/Prd'>Advanced Materials/Prd</option>
                            <option value='Advertising Agencies'>Advertising Agencies</option>
                            <option value='Advertising Sales'>Advertising Sales</option>
                            <option value='Advertising Services'>Advertising Services</option>
                         </select>
                         </label>




          <input class='btn btn-primary' id='search' type='button' value='Search' />
            <button class='btn' id='reset'>Reset</button>

            </div>





          <p class='alert alert-info lead' id='result_count'></p>


    </p>  </p>
    </p>  </p>
    </p>  </p>


        </div>


        <div class='span8'>
          <div id='map_canvas'></div>
          <div class='well'>
            <div id='results_list'></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="source/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.address.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="maps_lib.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      //<![CDATA[
        $(window).resize(function () {
          var h = $(window).height(),
            offsetTop = 90; // Calculate the top offset

          $('#map_canvas').css('height', (h - offsetTop));
        }).resize();

        $(function() {
          MapsLib.initialize();
          $("#search_address").geocomplete();

          $(':checkbox').click(function(){
            MapsLib.doSearch();
          });

          $(':radio').click(function(){
            MapsLib.doSearch();
          });

          $('#search_radius').change(function(){
            MapsLib.doSearch();
          });

          $('#select_type').change(function(){
            MapsLib.doSearch();
          });
           $('#select_type1').change(function(){
            MapsLib.doSearch();
          });
            $('#select_type2').change(function(){
            MapsLib.doSearch();
          });

          $('#search').click(function(){
            MapsLib.doSearch();
          });

          $('#find_me').click(function(){
            MapsLib.findMe(); 
            return false;
          });

          $('#reset').click(function(){
            $.address.parameter('address','');
            MapsLib.initialize(); 
            return false;
          });

          $(":text").keydown(function(e){
              var key =  e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
              if(key == 13) {
                  $('#search').click();
                  return false;
              }
          });
        });
      //]]>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

maps_lib.js

```
/*!
 * Searchable Map Template with Google Fusion Tables
 * http://derekeder.com/searchable_map_template/
 *
 * Copyright 2012, Derek Eder
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * https://github.com/derekeder/FusionTable-Map-Template/wiki/License
 *
 * Date: 12/10/2012
 *
 */

var MapsLib = MapsLib || {};
var MapsLib = {

  //Setup section - put your Fusion Table details here
  //Using the v1 Fusion Tables API. See https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/migration_guide for more info

  //the encrypted Table ID of your Fusion Table (found under File => About)
  //NOTE: numeric IDs will be deprecated soon
  fusionTableId:      "1f8rnajgS2iSVwwBR1NwXwImUuFB7VCpOg1-IfCs",

  //*New Fusion Tables Requirement* API key. found at https://code.google.com/apis/console/
  //*Important* this key is for demonstration purposes. please register your own.
  googleApiKey:       "API KEY",

  //name of the location column in your Fusion Table.
  //NOTE: if your location column name has spaces in it, surround it with single quotes
  //example: locationColumn:     "'my location'",
  locationColumn:     "Address",

  map_centroid:       new google.maps.LatLng(17,15), //center that your map defaults to
  locationScope:      "",      //geographical area appended to all address searches
  recordName:         "Store",       //for showing number of results
  recordNamePlural:   "Stores",

  searchRadius:       805,            //in meters ~ 1/2 mile
  defaultZoom:        2,             //zoom level when map is loaded (bigger is more zoomed in)
  addrMarkerImage: 'http://derekeder.com/images/icons/blue-pushpin.png',
  currentPinpoint: null,

  initialize: function() {
    $( "#result_count" ).html("");

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: MapsLib.defaultZoom,
      center: MapsLib.map_centroid,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas")[0],myOptions);

    // maintains map centerpoint for responsive design
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
        MapsLib.calculateCenter();
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        map.setCenter(MapsLib.map_centroid);
    });

    MapsLib.searchrecords = null;

    //reset filters
    $("#search_address").val(MapsLib.convertToPlainString($.address.parameter('address')));
    var loadRadius = MapsLib.convertToPlainString($.address.parameter('radius'));
    if (loadRadius != "") $("#search_radius").val(loadRadius);
    else $("#search_radius").val(MapsLib.searchRadius);
    $(":checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
    $("#result_count").hide();

    //-----custom initializers-------



    //run the default search
    MapsLib.doSearch();
  },

  doSearch: function(location) {
    MapsLib.clearSearch();
    var address = $("#search_address").val();
    MapsLib.searchRadius = $("#search_radius").val();

    var whereClause = MapsLib.locationColumn + " not equal to ''";

    //-----custom filters-------

   if ( $("#select_type").val() != "") {
      whereClause += " AND 'Category' = '" + $("#select_type").val() + "'";
      }

    if ( $("#select_type1").val() != "") {
      whereClause += " AND 'sex' = '" + $("#select_type1").val() + "'";
      }


    if ( $("#select_type2").val() != "") {
      whereClause += " AND 'Subindustry' = '" + $("#select_type2").val() + "'";
      }



    //-------end of custom filters--------

    if (address != "") {
      if (address.toLowerCase().indexOf(MapsLib.locationScope) == -1)
        address = address + " " + MapsLib.locationScope;

      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          MapsLib.currentPinpoint = results[0].geometry.location;

          $.address.parameter('address', encodeURIComponent(address));
          $.address.parameter('radius', encodeURIComponent(MapsLib.searchRadius));
          map.setCenter(MapsLib.currentPinpoint);
          map.setZoom(14);

          if (MapsLib.searchRadius == "400")
            map.setZoom(16);
          else if (MapsLib.searchRadius == "805")
            map.setZoom(15);
          else if (MapsLib.searchRadius == "1610")
            map.setZoom(14);
          else if (MapsLib.searchRadius == "3220")
            map.setZoom(13);
          else if (MapsLib.searchRadius == "8050")
            map.setZoom(12);
          else if (MapsLib.searchRadius == "16100")
            map.setZoom(11);
          else if (MapsLib.searchRadius == "40250")
            map.setZoom(09);
          else if (MapsLib.searchRadius == "80500")
            map.setZoom(08);
          else if (MapsLib.searchRadius == "161000")
            map.setZoom(07);
          else if (MapsLib.searchRadius == "402500")
            map.setZoom(06);
          else if (MapsLib.searchRadius == "805000")
            map.setZoom(05);
          else if (MapsLib.searchRadius == "1610000")
            map.setZoom(04);
          else
            map.setZoom(14);


          MapsLib.addrMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: MapsLib.currentPinpoint,
            map: map,
            icon: MapsLib.addrMarkerImage,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title:address
          });

          whereClause += " AND ST_INTERSECTS(" + MapsLib.locationColumn + ", CIRCLE(LATLNG" + MapsLib.currentPinpoint.toString() + "," + MapsLib.searchRadius + "))";

          MapsLib.drawSearchRadiusCircle(MapsLib.currentPinpoint);
          MapsLib.submitSearch(whereClause, map, MapsLib.currentPinpoint);
        }
        else {
          alert("We could not find your address: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
    else { //search without geocoding callback
      MapsLib.submitSearch(whereClause, map);
    }
  },

  submitSearch: function(whereClause, map, location) {
    //get using all filters
    //NOTE: styleId and templateId are recently added attributes to load custom marker styles and info windows
    //you can find your Ids inside the link generated by the 'Publish' option in Fusion Tables
    //for more details, see https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#WorkingStyles

    MapsLib.searchrecords = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        from:   MapsLib.fusionTableId,
        select: MapsLib.locationColumn,
        where:  whereClause
      },
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    });
    MapsLib.searchrecords.setMap(map);
    MapsLib.getCount(whereClause);
    MapsLib.getList(whereClause);
  },

  clearSearch: function() {
    if (MapsLib.searchrecords != null)
      MapsLib.searchrecords.setMap(null);
    if (MapsLib.addrMarker != null)
      MapsLib.addrMarker.setMap(null);
    if (MapsLib.searchRadiusCircle != null)
      MapsLib.searchRadiusCircle.setMap(null);
  },

  findMe: function() {
    // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
    var foundLocation;

    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        foundLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
        MapsLib.addrFromLatLng(foundLocation);
      }, null);
    }
    else {
      alert("Sorry, we could not find your location.");
    }
  },

  addrFromLatLng: function(latLngPoint) {
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latLngPoint}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
          $('#search_address').val(results[1].formatted_address);
          $('.hint').focus();
          MapsLib.doSearch();
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  },

  drawSearchRadiusCircle: function(point) {
      var circleOptions = {
        strokeColor: "#4b58a6",
        strokeOpacity: 0.3,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: "#4b58a6",
        fillOpacity: 0.05,
        map: map,
        center: point,
        clickable: false,
        zIndex: -1,
        radius: parseInt(MapsLib.searchRadius)
      };
      MapsLib.searchRadiusCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
  },

  query: function(selectColumns, whereClause, callback) {
    var queryStr = [];
    queryStr.push("SELECT " + selectColumns);
    queryStr.push(" FROM " + MapsLib.fusionTableId);
    queryStr.push(" WHERE " + whereClause);

    var sql = encodeURIComponent(queryStr.join(" "));
    $.ajax({url: "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql="+sql+"&callback="+callback+"&key="+MapsLib.googleApiKey, dataType: "jsonp"});
  },

  handleError: function(json) {
    if (json["error"] != undefined) {
      var error = json["error"]["errors"]
      console.log("Error in Fusion Table call!");
      for (var row in error) {
        console.log(" Domain: " + error[row]["domain"]);
        console.log(" Reason: " + error[row]["reason"]);
        console.log(" Message: " + error[row]["message"]);
      }
    }
  },

  getCount: function(whereClause) {
    var selectColumns = "Count()";
    MapsLib.query(selectColumns, whereClause,"MapsLib.displaySearchCount");
  },

  displaySearchCount: function(json) {
    MapsLib.handleError(json);
    var numRows = 0;
    if (json["rows"] != null)
      numRows = json["rows"][0];

    var name = MapsLib.recordNamePlural;
    if (numRows == 1)
    name = MapsLib.recordName;
    $( "#result_count" ).fadeOut(function() {
        $( "#result_count" ).html(MapsLib.addCommas(numRows) + " " + name + " found");
      });
    $( "#result_count" ).fadeIn();
  },

getList: function(whereClause) {
  var selectColumns = "StoreName, Address, Contact, Website";
  MapsLib.query(selectColumns, whereClause, "MapsLib.displayList");
},

displayList: function(json) {
  MapsLib.handleError(json);
  var data = json["rows"];
  var template = "";

  var results = $("#results_list");
  results.hide().empty(); //hide the existing list and empty it out first

  if (data == null) {
    //clear results list
    results.append("<li><span class='lead'>No results found</span></li>");
  }
  else {
    for (var row in data) {
      template = "\
        <div class='row-fluid item-list'>\
          <div class='span12'>\
            <span class='lead'>" + data[row][0] + "\</span>\
            <br />\
            " + data[row][4] + "\
            <br />\
            " + data[row][5] + "\
            <br />\
            <a href='" + data[row][6] + "'>\
                <span>" + data[row][7] + "\</span>\
            </a>\
            <br />\
            <a onClick=''>\
                <span style='color: red;'>See on Map</span>\
            </a>\
          </div>\
        </div>"
      results.append(template);
    }
  }
  results.fadeIn();
},

  addCommas: function(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
      x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
  },

  // maintains map centerpoint for responsive design
  calculateCenter: function() {
    center = map.getCenter();
  },

  //converts a slug or query string in to readable text
  convertToPlainString: function(text) {
    if (text == undefined) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(text);
  }

  //-----custom functions-------
  // NOTE: if you add custom functions, make sure to append each one with a comma, except for the last one.
  // This also applies to the convertToPlainString function above

  //-----end of custom functions-------
}
```

[image]

Comment: [example of opening a FusionTables InfoWindow from a click on a "sidebar" entry](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html) (concept will work if you have externally geocoded the entries in the table, not if they are "auto-geocoded" by FusionTables)

Comment: I am a total beginner and have no idea how to geocode 'externally'. Can I provide IDs to the rows and do something like onClick on the names? Can you have a quick look at the JS and advice me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's not as easy as it seems.

The location of a feature(e.g. marker) on a FusionTableLayer isn't available until you really click on it(this click can't be simulated).

You can't get the LatLng of the feature with the query, because you've stored addresses and not LatLng's inside the FusionTable.

Although the API knows the LatLng's of the addresses, there is no way to access them.

So the only thing you may do is:

1. Take the address of the row
2. use google.maps.Geocoder to geocode this address
3. open a custom InfoWindow(content populated by the properties of the row) at the LatLng returned by the geocoder.

Comment: If I add latitude and longitude columns in my table and add markers with those instead of addresses, will it be possible then? I found this http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/fusion-tables-sidebar.html example but I don't know which code to add where in the template i am using.

Comment: With a LatLng instead of the address you wouldn't need to geocode the address, but you still need to create and open a custom InfoWindow.

Comment: I have added latitude and longitude columns to my table and mapped them. I am having difficulty in creating infowindows as you said above.

Comment: I added 'var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
' and 'suppressInfoWindows : true', however, when I add ' google.maps.event.addListener(MapsLib.searchrecords, "click", function(evt) {
          openInfoWindow(evt);
    });' it gives me an error Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather add a comment to Dr.Molle's answer, but thanks to Stack Overflow's point system, I have to add an answer even though I don't think this will be truly useful because I can't be very specific.  I'm assuming that's because the goal is to get me to *answer* questions, not just talk about answers ;)

Dr.Molle was on the right track, but invoking the geocoder on every click is not only painfully slow, but every IP only gets so many geocoder requests per day.  So:

Create a column that has a unique identifier.  Add a listener to the marker so that when clicked, it will query your table for that ID.  When the results come in, create an InfoWindow (sorry, no help here) with the returned data.

Here's a sample that does exactly what you're asking for:
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_infowindow_content

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am a beginner and very raw. I can work with instructions and sample codes. I don't see a marker function in my js file except for the one that drops at the searched address.

Comment: Edited answer with a sample